# Variable Assignment in Function Header

Tags: c++

What is the advantage (if one exists) to assigning a variable in the header of a function or constructor?  In other words, what is the difference between the following two sets of code and why would I prefer one over the other?

Example 1:

```
class A {
 private:
  char* b;
 public:
  A(size_t var = 8*1024*1024) {
    ...
    b = new char[var];
    ...
  }
  ...
};
```

Example 2:

```
class A {
 private:
  char* b;
 public:
  A() {
    const size_t var = 8*1024*1024;
    ...
    b = new char[var];
    ...
  }
  ...
};
```

I appreciate any constructive input.

Comment: One allows you to set the size of the array data member and the other one doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a default argument. It allows the caller to call the function without passing an argument, in which case the default value is used.

So in the first example, one could call:

```
A* myADefault = new A(); // creates A with default value (8*1024*1024)
A* myLargerA = new A(16*1024*1024); // creates A passing 16*1024*1024 instead of the default
```

(for more info, look at the "Default values in parameters" section in this tutorial: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions2/)

Comment: @juanchopanza I just wanted to be explicit about calling the constructor. I was going to just have `A a();` to explicitly show that the constructor is called without arguments, but then I got confused if that would be interpreted as a function declaration by the compiler... :P

Comment: Ah OK, I see. You can use `{}` in C++11, that avoids the vexing parse. You can also say `A a = A()` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

It's really different.

The first represents a default value, that means you can declare `A test` or `A test2(42)`. In `test`, `b` will have a size of 8*1024*1024. In `test2`, `b` will have a size of 42.

The second snippet is just a constante value.

You will prefere one to other depending on your needs ...

Answer (score 2):

This is a so called default argument: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91563f79(v=vs.80).aspx

The difference is that you can set value for the the `var` in the first case but not in the second case.

Answer (score 1):

What you've wrote are two different beings : in the first example, var is an `input parameter with a default value` of 8*1024*1024 while in the second, it is a `local const variable`. Even if the behaviour is the same, the inner structure isn't.

To anwser your question about the preference of one method over the other, it depends on your design : the former add some flexibility, but also expose a parameter which maybe should stay hidden, while the latter is more rigid, but also less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

But neither case is particularly good.  Member variables should be initialized in constructor initialization lists.  That is the only way to initialize a `const` member variable, for example.

```
class A {
     private:
         char* b;
     public:
         A(size_t var = 8*1024*1024): b(new char[var]) {
            ...
        }
        ~A() {
            delete [] b;
        }
};
```

Even then, a smart pointer would be better for `b`.